# split a string at the 4th occurence of a comma in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a list

```
     set list "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx"
```

Now I want to split this list on the 4th occurence of the comma.
I want the list to be divided into two lists:

```
 A = abc,def,ghi,jkl
 B = mno,pqr,stu,vwx
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried ?

Comment: I tried using split: 
     split $list ,
But this gives me the entire list without commas: abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx
I am not able to figure out how should i specify that i need a split after the 4th comma

Answer (score 4):

How about simply using the list operators to `split` and re-`join`:

```
puts [set A [join [lrange [split $list ,] 0 3] ,]]
puts [set B [join [lrange [split $list ,] 4 end] ,]]
```

Or, if you wanted to go the regexp route, do it in one operation:

```
regexp -- {((?:\w+,){3}\w+),(.*)} $list --> A B
puts $A
puts $B
```

Comment: Nice regexp! Very elegant!

Comment: @surabhi-nayar Did this work for you? Feel free to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
set list "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx"    

regexp -- {(\w+,){3}\w+} $list A
regsub -- "${A}," $list {} B

puts $A
puts $B
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather complicated example :)

```
set occurence 4
set slice_position 0
set list "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx"

for {set i  0} {$i < $occurence} {incr i} {
    set slice_position [string first "," $list [expr $slice_position + 1]]
    if {$slice_position == -1} {
        break
    }
}

puts [string range $list 0 $slice_position-1]
puts [string range $list $slice_position+1 end]
```